# Catch event when a process is halted for debugging

Tags: c, linux

I have multiple processes running and exchanging data via a communication service running in an extra process. This makes debugging quite hard as the other processes (of course) keep running and exchanging data when I hit a debugging breakpoint in one process.

Is there a way on a Linux system with C to globally detect if a process is halted for debugging?

Then I could either centrally kill -STOP the other processes or have each process catch the event and stop processing data.

(I don't need ultra-high precision, it would be ok if the other processes continue for a few cycles)

Comment: Many debuggers will have a way to run an external command when a breakpoint is hit, e.g the `commands` command in `gdb`.  Would that serve your purpose?  Having some sort of global detection wouldn't really seem to me like the right way to go about this.

Comment: In general, no - only the tracing process can get information (via signals and introspection) about the traced / debugged process through the `ptrace()` syscalls.   If you can start all of you processes from gdb, there are good facilities in the debugger itself for determining what other processes and threads being run do when a breakpoint is reached....

Comment: Thank you both very much. I'll investigate what gdb has to offer for me in this regard then - this is probably much more straight forward than my initial idea.